# How to get access to SQLAlchemy automap?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy [automap](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html). When I described structure Declarative I have got [backref](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html) property:

> The above configuration establishes a collection of `Address` objects on `User` called `User.addresses`.

But now with automap my code is like next:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sql_test.db', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sess = Session()
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
User = Base.classes.Users
addresses = Base.classes.addresses

answer = sess.query(User).filter(User.id==1).first()
print('type:', type(answer)) # will print: class User
```

But how I can get access to `addresses` here? I tried: `answer.addresses` and so one, but it is not working.

Users:

```
CREATE TABLE "Users"(
    "id"   Integer PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" Text,
CONSTRAINT "unique_id" UNIQUE ( "id" ) )
```

Addresses:

```
CREATE TABLE "addresses"(
    "id"      Integer PRIMARY KEY,
    "email"   Text,
    "user_id" Integer,
    CONSTRAINT "lnk_Users_addresses" FOREIGN KEY ( "user_id" ) REFERENCES "Users"( "id" ), 
CONSTRAINT "unique_id" UNIQUE ( "id" ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default naming scheme](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#sqlalchemy.ext.automap.name_for_collection_relationship) for collection relationships is:

```
return referred_cls.__name__.lower() + "_collection"
```

So given that you have a model class `addresses`, then your relationship should be

```
User.addresses_collection
```

If you wish to alter this behaviour, pass your own implementation as the [`name_for_collection_relationship=`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#sqlalchemy.ext.automap.AutomapBase.prepare.params.name_for_collection_relationship) keyword argument to `AutomapBase.prepare()`.

Comment: How I can get `backref` name generated by automap?

Comment: The default scheme for a scalar relationship should be `referred_cls.__name__.lower()`, so `addresses.users` (note that you've named the table using the plural form, mirrored in having to access it as `Base.classes.Users`). All in all have a look at ["Relationship Detection"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#relationship-detection).

Comment: Could you show an example how to add it's name to variable? I can't understand how to use this return

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question. What name, and what variable? Do you mean the user's name, given an address instance? In that case `uname = addr.users.name`.

Comment: I do not understand how to call function `return referred_cls.__name__.lower() + "_collection"` to get result to variable.
like: `my_var = User__name__.lower() + "_collection"` or how?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow you. Try explaining what you're trying to accomplish, instead of how.